# Why this sequence converges to $0$ almost surely

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

I have this sequence of random variables:
$$X_{1}(w) = \mathbb{1}_{(1/2,1]}(w), X_{2}(w) = \mathbb{1}_{(0,1/2]}(w), X_{3}(w) = \mathbb{1}_{(3/4,1]}(w), X_{4}(w) = \mathbb{1}_{(1/2,3/4]}(w) ...$$

I know and I understand that this sequence converges in Probability: $P(|X_{n}|>0) \longrightarrow 0$, $\textbf{but not almost sure}$, because since for any $\omega \in (0,1]$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there exist $\textbf{n}$, $\textbf{m} \geq N$ such that $X_{n} = 1$ and $X_{m} = 0$.

But Why this sequence bellow converges to $0$ almost surely?

$$Y_{1}(w) = \mathbb{1}_{(0,1/2]}(w), Y_{2}(w) = \mathbb{1}_{(0,1/2]}(w), Y_{3}(w) = \mathbb{1}_{(0,1/4]}(w), Y_{4}(w) = \mathbb{1}_{(0,1/4]}(w) ...$$

Thanks guys!

Comment: It would help to clarify a few things: (1) how is $w$ generated or what distribution is it from, and (2) what is the general formula for $Y_i$?

Comment: @se2018 I took this example from this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2806377/convergence-modes First answer, second example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the probability space we're working on is $\Omega = (0, 1]$. Note for any $\omega \in \Omega$, there exists $K$ such that we have $\frac{1}{k} < \omega$ for all $k \geq K$. In particular if $Y (\omega)= 1_{(0, 1/k]}(\omega)$ then $Y(\omega) = 0$. Eventually all the $Y$'s take the form $1_{(0, 1/k]}$ for $k \geq K$, hence $\lim_n Y_n(\omega) = 0$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$. This gives almost sure convergence.

In this case we showed convergence for all $\omega \in \Omega$ but you actually only show it for all $\omega \in \Omega_0$ where  $\Omega_0 \subset \Omega$ is of probability 1.

Comment: I have a question. Why it is wrong to consider that for $k \leq K$ this sequence will not alternate its values between $1$ and $0$? Why I can use this idea for the first sequence and I cant use it for the second sequence (the one that you answered me).

Comment: You don't care about $Y_n(\omega)$ for small $n$, we're taking limits so we only care about behaviour for large values of $n$. $Y_n(\omega)$ will eventually be constantly 0. However in the second sequence, the $X_n(\omega)$ take values 1 and 0 infinitely often and hence can't converge to anything.

Comment: "$Yn(ω)$ will eventually be constantly 0". This I cant understand. Why you can say that? The $Y_{n}(\omega)$ also takes values 1 and 0, right?

Comment: No, that's the point. If $n$ is big enough, then $Y_n = 1_{(0, 1/k]}$ for $k \geq K$ where $\frac{1}{K} < \omega$, hence $Y_n(\omega) = 0$.s Yes, for small value of $n$ we will have $Y_n(\omega) = 1$. But for large values of $n$ that stops happening.